Guidance on Implementing Delta-Based State Sync for Web3 Blockchain
I’m developing a Web3 blockchain module to synchronize state between nodes using delta updates. The goal is to minimize data transfer, particularly for sidechains or shard chains, by sending only state changes (deltas) instead of the full state.
I came across delta synchronization while researching synchronization methods and found it intriguing for optimizing bandwidth usage in blockchain networks. However, I’m unsure how to effectively apply this concept in a Web3 context, especially when syncing state across multiple nodes.
I have a basic understanding of how delta functions work but haven’t yet started implementation. I’m looking for guidance on:
How to calculate and apply delta updates in a decentralized network.
Best practices for handling state consistency and ensuring no data loss during sync.
Potential challenges with using this method for blockchain nodes.
Any insights or suggestions on where to start would be greatly appreciated!

You can think Ethereum blocks themselves are delta updates. Each block contains transactions which themselves are delta updates to EVM world state.
The full state is never transferred but always synced by a client.

How do delta updates differ from the changes(in  context of Merkle tree)already present in traditional blockchain blocks? Can I focus on optimizing specific parts like syncing state between sidechains, shard chains, or lightweight nodes?

Because delta updates are a generic concept, it is impossible to answer this question, unless there are specific concrete details.

I think this question would be better off on a generic discussion forum like EthDev Reddit, Eth Magicians, or others. Because there is "no answer".
